# Why is that happend to replace() in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I was doing Leetcode questions, I found a problem in replace() of Javascript.

This is for just javascript.

```
var str = "1.1.1.1";
str = str.replace(/./g, "[.]");


I expect the output of
1[.]1[.]1[.]1
but the actual output is:
[.][.][.][.][.][.][.]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

`/./g` matches everything. Escape the `.`:

```js
str = str.replace(/\./g, "[.]");
```